# Windows Function Syntax Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Here is my windows syntax for Postgres I'm using in rails:

```
select *
from (
  select *,row_number() over(partition by category order by random()) as ordinal
  from question) X
where ordinal = 1;
```

I have tested this syntax I was given in rails console and it returned

```
SyntaxError: unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
...m ( select *, row_number() over(partition by category order ...
...                               ^
```

I have no idea whats wrong with my code and how to fix it.

Here is my Question controller:

```
class QuestionnairesController < ApplicationController

def index
    binding.pry
    @question = Questionnaire.find(params[:category_id])
    @category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
    @videos = VideoClue.find(params[:category_id])
    ###This finds all the questions from the question table by their category_id. Whenever I select a category, it matches the question related to the category

    render :show
    ###render :show Renders Html page
end

def choose_answer

    @question = Questionnaire.find(params[:id])
    @choices = @question.choices
    #list all from the choices column

    render :choose_answer

end

def results

    @question_data= Questionnaire.where(id: params[:id])
    @correct_answer = @question_data[0].correct_answer
    @selected_answer = params[:choice]
    #In order to compare the user selected answer to the right answer, I had to make 'choice' as a param and created a variable that is equal to the params so it will render the success and error pages correctly.

    if @selected_answer == @correct_answer
        render :success
    else
        render :error
    end












    end





end
```

My Question table:

```
Questionnaire.create({question: "In what year did MTV (Music Television) premiere and what was the first music video the channel aired?", choices:['1982 Michael Jackson Bille Jean', '1984 Madonna Like a virgin', '1981 The Buggles Video Killed The Radio Star'], correct_answer:"1981 The Buggles Video Killed The Radio Star", category_id:1})
Questionnaire.create({question:"This game launched in 1991 on Sega Genesis which the player's mission is to collect as many golden rings as possible", choices:['Battletoads', 'Sonic The Hedgehog', 'Jewel Master'], correct_answer: "Sonic The Hedgehog", category_id:1})
Questionnaire.create({question: "This sitcom featured four girls living under one roof. They attended the same boarding school, ran a shop together and reside in a town called Peekskill." , choices:['Designing Women', 'The Facts of Life', 'Girlfriends'], correct_answer:'The Facts of Life', category_id: 2})
Questionnaire.create({question: "This martial arts film premiere in 1985 which featured a young man who studies Bruce Lee's techniques while on the search for his master. This was set in New York City." , choices:['The Last Dragon', 'The Karate Kid', 'Big Trouble in Little China'], correct_answer:'The Last Dragon', category_id: 3})
Questionnaire.create({question:"This game launched in 1991 on Sega Genesis which the player's mission is to collect as many golden rings as possible", choices:['Battletoads', 'Sonic The Hedgehog', 'Jewel Master'], correct_answer: "Sonic The Hedgehog", category_id:4})
```

Where does my window syntax goes?

Comment: Did you paste that straight into the rails console?

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? (show the output of `select version()`)

Comment: Yes I did paste into rails console. I believe I'm using version 9.3.9.

Comment: Perhaps insert one space beetwen `...over` and `(partition...`

Comment: I've tried that but still the same error